# How to squentially(max-min-max-mix....) print Binary Struct Tree with traversal method?

Tags: c

I need to print without making a change in the tree. Also the dynamic array is forbidden. One problem can be the same elements in that tree.

```
int find_the_minimum_value(current_minimum_value)
{

}
int find_the_maximum_value(current_maximum_value)
{

}

void traverse_bst(bst *bst_)
{
    int current_maximum_value,current_minimum_value;
    int max_counter,min_counter;
    bst *temp;

    for ( temp = bst_; temp->right != NULL; temp = temp->right);
    current_maximum_value = temp->data;

    for ( temp = bst_; temp->left != NULL; temp = temp->left);
    current_minimum_value = temp->data;

    while(1)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also, please use the title as a short summary of your question or problem, and put the actual question inside the main text.

Comment: Do you mean "Binary Search Tree"?